# Preciso de ajuda urgente, não consegui interpretar essa atividade e não consigo ajeitar o código

Tags: php, html, xampp

Meu professor me passou uma lição de PHP e juro que não entendi praticamente nada, pedir ajuda pra ele tá fora de questão principalmente porque ele é muito ignorante e não gosta quando outros alunos fazem qualquer tipo de pergunta. Aqui o texto que ele mandou:

[image: Atividade PHP]

Só consegui fazer isso do código, que não foi muito pra frente:

```
<?php


$dados = array('<p>nome: <br>', 'idade: <br>', 'salário: 1500<br>', '<p>ativo', '<p>não ativo');

$bonificacao = ($dados[2] / 100 * 10) + 1500;


foreach ($dados as $funcionario1) 
{
    $funcionario1[0] . 'Ferdinando';
    $funcionario1[1] . '25';
    echo $funcionario1;
}

foreach ($dados as $funcionario2) 
{
    $funcionario2[0] . 'Irineu';
    $funcionario2[1] . '40';
    echo $funcionario2;
}

foreach ($dados as $funcionario3) 
{
    $funcionario3[0] . 'Letícia';
    $funcionario3[1] . '19';
    echo $funcionario3;
}


?>
```

Isto foi imprimido na página:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É uma atividade para mostrar que você aprendeu a manipular uma matriz (array) e fazer loops, e utilizar variáveis.

```
$dados = array(
  array(
    'nome' => 'joao',
    'salario' => 100,
    'ativo' => false
  ),
  array(
    'nome' => 'maria',
    'salario' => 200,
    'ativo' => true
  ),
);

$bonificacao = 0.10;

foreach ($dados as $funcionario) {
  if (! $funcionario['ativo']) {
    continue;
  }
  $funcionario['salario'] += floatval($funcionario['salario']) * $bonificacao;

  echo $funcionario['nome'] . ' - ' . $funcionario['salario'];
}
```

Comment: A parte mais engraçada é que ele não ensinou nada disso, só mostrou os arrays, já cheguei até a reclamar desse professor com a coordenação, mesmo assim, obrigado cara!

Comment: Só complementando. "A partir do PHP 5.4 você também pode utilizar a sintaxe contraída de array, que troca array() por []" Segue a DOC https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php